# Which is better with respect to database performance?

Tags: sql, db2, database-performance

We are expecting null values in a particular column.  We would like to capture them in the output also.  There are two possible values other than null.  They are WE and EA.  So, out of these two syntax given below, which one performs better?

```
…(  "Src_Dtl"."REGN" not in ('WE','EA') or
      "Src_Dtl"."REGN" is null)…
```

or

```
...(coalesce(CVRG_REGN, ‘WE’))...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you  juts check it by running both queries or inspecting execution plan?

Comment: col not in ('WE','EA') will never be TRUE, because either the value is WE or EA, or it's a NULL value - which results in NULL. I.e. IS NULL is enough. But go with COALESCE since it's very convenient!

Answer (score 0):

Null values always returns false for comparisons so  not in ('a','b') a null comparison would return false so it would not be included.  We are forced to add a 2nd clause or something is null.  This is two operations on the data.

The coalesce function says give me the first non null value in the list.  It is one operation (check if the value is null) and has two possible outcomes.  Because this is one operation it is faster than doing two operations.